# Mean for multiple rows based on two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame loaded in R and I need to calculate mean for each voivodeship for each year. The problem is that I've tried to use rowMeans() function, but the final result is not correct. I also tried a for loop to calculate mean for each year, but I received an error :(

I need a mean using formula for each year (2006 - 2018): gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2006..ha. / gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2006....

My data:

```
structure(list(Kod = c(0L, 200000L, 400000L, 600000L, 800000L, 
                          1000000L), Nazwa = c("POLSKA", "DOLNOŚLĄSKIE", "KUJAWSKO-POMORSKIE", 
                                                 "LUBELSKIE", "LUBUSKIE", "ŁÓDZKIE"),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2006.... = c(9187L,  481L, 173L,
                                                                  1072L, 256L, 218L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2007.... =
                    c(11870L,  652L, 217L, 1402L, 361L, 261L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2008.... = c(14896L,  879L, 258L,
                                                                  1566L, 480L, 314L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2009.... =
                    c(17091L,  1021L, 279L, 1710L, 579L, 366L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2010.... = c(20582L,  1227L, 327L,
                                                                  1962L, 833L, 420L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2011.... =
                    c(23449L,  1322L, 371L, 2065L, 1081L, 478L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2012.... = c(25944L,  1312L, 390L,
                                                                  2174L, 1356L, 518L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2013.... =
                    c(26598L,  1189L, 415L, 2129L, 1422L, 528L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2014.... = c(24829L,  1046L, 401L,
                                                                  1975L, 1370L, 508L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2015.... =
                    c(22277L,  849L, 363L, 1825L, 1202L, 478L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2016.... = c(22435L,  813L, 470L,
                                                                  1980L, 1148L, 497L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2017.... =
                    c(20257L,  741L, 419L, 1904L, 948L, 477L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2018.... = c(19207L,  713L, 395L,
                                                                  1948L, 877L, 491L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2006..ha. =
                    c(228038L,  19332L, 4846L, 19957L, 12094L, 3378L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2007..ha. =
                    c(287529L,  21988L, 5884L, 23934L, 18201L, 3561L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2008..ha. =
                    c(314848L,  28467L, 5943L, 26892L, 18207L, 4829L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2009..ha. =
                    c(367062L,  26427L, 6826L, 30113L, 22929L, 5270L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2010..ha. =
                    c(519069L,  39703L, 7688L, 34855L, 35797L, 7671L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2011..ha. =
                    c(605520L,  45547L, 8376L, 34837L, 44259L, 8746L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2012..ha. =
                    c(661688L,  44304L, 8813L, 37466L, 52581L, 9908L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2013..ha. =
                    c(669970L,  37455L, 11152L, 40819L, 54692L, 10342L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2014..ha. =
                    c(657902L,  37005L, 11573L, 38467L, 53300L, 11229L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2015..ha. =
                    c(580730L,  31261L, 10645L, 34052L, 46343L, 10158L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2016..ha. =
                    c(536579L,  29200L, 9263L, 31343L, 43235L, 9986L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2017..ha. =
                    c(494978L,  27542L, 8331L, 29001L, 37923L, 9260L),
                  gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2018..ha. =
                    c(484677L,  27357L, 7655L, 28428L, 37174L, 8905L), X = c(NA, NA, NA,
                                                                               NA,  NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My attempt:

```
rowMeans(dane_csv[sapply(dane_csv, is.numeric)])
```

Final layout (calculated in Excel):

[image: Final layout]

Comment: can you tell us what your desired output would look like for a year? You say you want means for each year which are in columns but then are attempting to get means from rows ....

Comment: I edited my question with output calculated in Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem - the following is a possible `tidyverse` solution, which uses 3 packages of it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
```

Please make sure to read the documentation on **[pivoting](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html)**!

```
df %>%
    # make data "long", excluding ID columns (not sure what "Kod" is you might remove it) 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(Kod, Nazwa), names_to = "NMS", values_to = "VALS") %>% 
    # use regex to get what we need from the before column names
                  # to get the year extract the first 4 digit number
    dplyr::mutate(YEAR = stringr::str_extract(NMS, pattern = "\\d{4}"), 
                  # detect if names contains 4 points "." to assign binary value 
                  # I am working arround using TRUE and FALSE as column names even for an intermediary column
                  # possibly you have no problem with this and might therefore remove the ifelse() call leaving just the the stringr::str_detect() part
                  DET = ifelse(stringr::str_detect(NMS, pattern = "\\.{4}"), "LOWER", "UPPER")) %>% 
    # now spread the data again to get the column to devide by in one line
    tidyr::pivot_wider(-NMS, names_from = DET, values_from = VALS) %>% 
    # perform needed calulation between columsn
    dplyr::mutate(DIF = UPPER/LOWER) %>% 
    # remove NA rows to prevent "empty columns
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(DIF)) %>%
    # make the data wide again, while removing the two intermediary columns
    tidyr::pivot_wider(-c(LOWER, UPPER), names_from = "YEAR", values_from = "DIF")

# A tibble: 6 x 16
      Kod Nazwa              `2006` `2007` `2008` `2009` `2010` `2011` `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018`  
    <int> <chr>               <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> 
1       0 POLSKA               24.8   24.2   21.1   21.5   25.2   25.8   25.5   25.2   26.5   26.1   23.9   24.4   25.2   
2  200000 DOLNOSLASKIE         40.2   33.7   32.4   25.9   32.4   34.5   33.8   31.5   35.4   36.8   35.9   37.2   38.4   
3  400000 KUJAWSKO-POMORSKIE   28.0   27.1   23.0   24.5   23.5   22.6   22.6   26.9   28.9   29.3   19.7   19.9   19.4   
4  600000 LUBELSKIE            18.6   17.1   17.2   17.6   17.8   16.9   17.2   19.2   19.5   18.7   15.8   15.2   14.6   
5  800000 LUBUSKIE             47.2   50.4   37.9   39.6   43.0   40.9   38.8   38.5   38.9   38.6   37.7   40.0   42.4   
6 1000000 LÓDZKIE              15.5   13.6   15.4   14.4   18.3   18.3   19.1   19.6   22.1   21.3   20.1   19.4   18.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Reshape (unpivot) the data to enable vectorised manipulation:
# reshaped_df => data.frame
reshaped_df <- reshape(
  df1,
  direction = "long",
  varying = names(df1)[!(names(df1) %in% c("Kod", "Nazwa"))],
  idvar = "Kod",
  timevar = "Metric",
  times = names(df1)[!(names(df1) %in% c("Kod", "Nazwa"))],
  v.names = "Value",
  new.row.names = seq_len(nrow(df1) * length(names(df1)[!(names(df1) %in% c("Kod", "Nazwa"))]))
)

# Feature engineer to derive and standardised vectors:
# transformed_df => data.frame
transformed_df <- transform(
  reshaped_df,
  Year = as.integer(
    gsub(".*\\.(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1", Metric)
  ),
  Kod = as.character(Kod),
  Numerator = ifelse(
    grepl(
      "gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych",
      Metric
    ),
    Value,
    0L
  ),
  Denominator = ifelse(
    grepl(
      "gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa",
      Metric
    ),
    Value, 
    0L
  )
)[,c("Kod", "Nazwa", "Year",  "Numerator", "Denominator")]

# Aggregate the data and calculate the mean for a given country 
# in a given year: aggregated_df => data.frame
aggregated_df <- transform(
  aggregate(
    .~Kod+Nazwa+Year,
    transformed_df, 
    FUN = sum
  ),
  Value = Numerator / Denominator
)[,c("Kod", "Nazwa", "Year", "Value")]

# Pivot the data so each row is a country and each column 
# a year: pivotted_df => data.frame
pivotted_df <- as.data.frame.matrix(
  xtabs(
    Value~Nazwa+Year,
    aggregated_df
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Order the rows and columns as required:
# formatted_df => data.frame 
formatted_df <- setNames(
  data.frame(
    transform(
      pivotted_df, 
      Nazwa = row.names(pivotted_df)
    )[match(df1$Nazwa, row.names(pivotted_df)),c("Nazwa", paste0("X", colnames(pivotted_df)))],
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    row.names = NULL
  ),
  c("Nazwa", colnames(pivotted_df))
)

# Display result to console: 
# data.frame => stdout(console)
formatted_df
```

Data:

```
    df1 <- structure(list(Kod = c(0L, 200000L, 400000L, 600000L, 800000L, 
1000000L), Nazwa = c("POLSKA", "DOLNOŚLĄSKIE", "KUJAWSKO-POMORSKIE", 
"LUBELSKIE", "LUBUSKIE", "ŁÓDZKIE"),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2006.... = c(9187L,  481L, 173L,
1072L, 256L, 218L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2007.... =
c(11870L,  652L, 217L, 1402L, 361L, 261L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2008.... = c(14896L,  879L, 258L,
1566L, 480L, 314L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2009.... =
c(17091L,  1021L, 279L, 1710L, 579L, 366L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2010.... = c(20582L,  1227L, 327L,
1962L, 833L, 420L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2011.... =
c(23449L,  1322L, 371L, 2065L, 1081L, 478L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2012.... = c(25944L,  1312L, 390L,
2174L, 1356L, 518L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2013.... =
c(26598L,  1189L, 415L, 2129L, 1422L, 528L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2014.... = c(24829L,  1046L, 401L,
1975L, 1370L, 508L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2015.... =
c(22277L,  849L, 363L, 1825L, 1202L, 478L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2016.... = c(22435L,  813L, 470L,
1980L, 1148L, 497L), gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2017.... =
c(20257L,  741L, 419L, 1904L, 948L, 477L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.gospodarstwa.2018.... = c(19207L,  713L, 395L,
1948L, 877L, 491L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2006..ha. =
c(228038L,  19332L, 4846L, 19957L, 12094L, 3378L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2007..ha. =
c(287529L,  21988L, 5884L, 23934L, 18201L, 3561L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2008..ha. =
c(314848L,  28467L, 5943L, 26892L, 18207L, 4829L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2009..ha. =
c(367062L,  26427L, 6826L, 30113L, 22929L, 5270L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2010..ha. =
c(519069L,  39703L, 7688L, 34855L, 35797L, 7671L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2011..ha. =
c(605520L,  45547L, 8376L, 34837L, 44259L, 8746L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2012..ha. =
c(661688L,  44304L, 8813L, 37466L, 52581L, 9908L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2013..ha. =
c(669970L,  37455L, 11152L, 40819L, 54692L, 10342L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2014..ha. =
c(657902L,  37005L, 11573L, 38467L, 53300L, 11229L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2015..ha. =
c(580730L,  31261L, 10645L, 34052L, 46343L, 10158L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2016..ha. =
c(536579L,  29200L, 9263L, 31343L, 43235L, 9986L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2017..ha. =
c(494978L,  27542L, 8331L, 29001L, 37923L, 9260L),
gospodarstwa.ogółem.powierzchnia.użytków.rolnych.2018..ha. =
c(484677L,  27357L, 7655L, 28428L, 37174L, 8905L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```